# Unauthorized Error 401 when trying to push notification from ESP32

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, esp32

I am trying to push notification from my ESP32 to my firebase project. When I run the project, it throws this error:

```
INVALID_KEY
Error 401
```

I don't understand why the key is invalid, I tried putting the legacy server key, I tried the Web key pair but also didn't work, I have been disperete to find an answer but no solution helped me.

```
String DEVICE_FCM_KEY = token.c_str();
  String FCM_API_KEY = "key=***************************";
  String FCM_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

  //Check the current connection status
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED && token != "")) {  
    //Specify the URL
    HTTPClient http;

    http.begin(FCM_URL);

    // Set headers
    http.addHeader("Authorization", FCM_API_KEY.c_str());
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    // Data string
    String data = "{\"registration_ids\": [\"" + DEVICE_FCM_KEY + "\"], \"notification\": {\"body\":\"" + body + "\", \"title\":\"" + title + "\"}}";

    //Make the request
    int httpCode = http.POST(data);

    //Check for the returning code
    if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {  
      Serial.println("Notification Sent To The Phone");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Error on sending notification");
      Serial.println(httpCode);
      Serial.println(http.getString());
    }

    http.end();  //Free the resources
  }
```